# Call WordPress autosave with JavaScript

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-3.9

WordPress with `3.9` version has refactored autosave feature [`#25272`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25272).

Is it still possible somehow to trigger autosave manually with JavaScript ?

Recently we could use `autosave()` function which is currently mocked with:

```
window.autosave = function(){};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931252/ajax-autosave-functionality

Comment: @ravipatel That's not the point - WP has autosave methods but they had been refactored and I cannot obtain, how to use it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading through the changelog of the ticket, it looks like they're still making their mind up about keeping the old function

```
window.autosave = function(){};
```

in the code for backwards compatibility. So many plugins currently use it that it would break so many websites with the update.

A patch was put in place but has not been added to the master `[#25272.6.patch][1]`

Best idea would be to ask within the ticket and hope that the backwards compatibility is kept in place until there is a surefire way documented.